# Kotlin says No cast needed but when removed new warnings appear

Tags: kotlin

```
sealed interface Result<out T> {
    data class Success<T>(val data: T) : Result<T>
    data class Error(val exception: Throwable? = null) : Result<Nothing>
    object Loading : Result<Nothing>
}

fun <T, R> Flow<T>.mapToResultUiState(
    onSuccess: (T) -> R,
    onLoading: () -> R,
    onError: (Throwable?) -> R
): Flow<R> {
    return this
        .map { Result.Success(it) as Result<T> }
        .onStart { emit(Result.Loading) }
        .catch { e -> emit(Result.Error(e)) }
        .map { result ->
            when (result) {
                is Result.Success -> onSuccess(result.data)
                is Result.Loading -> onLoading()
                is Result.Error -> onError(result.exception)
            }
        }
}
```

The IDE says "No cast needed" on `.map { Result.Success(it) as Result<T> }` but if I remove this I get many new Type mismatches warnings on the lines below it. Really confused as of why and how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE is a bit dumb sometimes, and doesn't see the full picture. It doesn't understand that you want `map` to return `Flow<Result<T>>`, so that you can emit other kinds of `Result<T>` later on.

The IDE only sees that you are casting a `Result.Success<T>` to `Result<T>`, and thinks that everything you can do with a `Result<T>`, you can do with `Result.Success<T>`, so it concludes that the cast is not "needed".

If you explicitly write type parameters for `map` instead, the IDE won't complain.

```
map<_, Result<T>> { Result.Success(it) }
```

Note that the type placeholder `_` is a Kotlin 1.8 feature. If you are using an older version, write `map<T, Result<T>>`.

In other cases, where specifying the type parameters is not as trivial (e.g. there are a lot of parameters you need to specify), you can assign the `Success<T>` to a `val`, explicitly typed `Result<T>`:

```
map { 
    val result: Result<T> = Result.Success(it)
    result
}
```

Alternatively, write an `asResult` extension function.

```
fun <T> Result<T>.asResult() = this
```

```
map { Result.Success(it).asResult() }
```